# Using .htaccess to Rewrite URLs with ID and Filename

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a URL with .htaccess and had a question that I'm unable to find an answer to after many hours of searching. And, it doesn't help that my regex skills aren't that great...

The underlying format for my URLs is this: `http://mysite.com/article.php?id=1`.

I would like to have a URL like this direct there: `http://mysite.com/article/1/made-up-irrelevant-title-slug`.

The problem is, I'd like the `article` to be a variable such that it could be changed to `page` and would direct to something like: `http://mysite.com/page.php?id=1`, from `http://mysite.com/page/1/made-up-page-name`.

If anyone knows how this is properly written, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Turn on Rewrites
RewriteEngine on

# Do not rewrite existing files, directories, or symlinks.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Rewrite /COMPONENT/ID/TITLE -> COMPONENT.php?id=ID
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/.*$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason, there's some server directories before the domain name starts, and it loads a 404 page. IE It's going to the server path instead of the web path. Do I have to add `%{HTTP_HOST}` somewhere?

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /` before the conditions and rules.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now the stylesheet disappeared, but I'm sure that's an easy fix I can find!

Comment: @Justin - you need to add a forward slash infront of all file links except PHP include and require functions

Comment: @Justin - I took it a little further with my answer, but you might want to look into it as it covers using custom URLs like you used as example in your question, but getting rid of the preceeding ID