# Possibility Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

So, i'm curious about the fact if it's possible to rewrite a parameter but keep the value be able to be readen.

So for example:

```
www.domain.com/product/my-awesome-product-laser-pen
```

Which basically (in code behind) is:

```
wwww.domain.com/product.php?id=191
```

Basically, I just want to be able to GET the ID (to search up the product inside of my database) and let the client see it's name.

Is it possible, using only Htaccess?

Comment: Refer to :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070849/using-htaccess-to-rewrite-urls-with-id-and-filename

Comment: @user3107804 True, but if you pay attention to the example i'm displaying the ID has never been stored inside of the URL. And that's what i'm looking for

Comment: Bilal , that isn't possible . You can't get a numbric value from a non-numbric string.

Comment: @starkeen I'm not sure if I can post URL's onto this website but there is a way, i'm not sure how but this is an example of a live demonstration: http://putlocker.is/watch-terminator-genisys-online-free-putlocker.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a `191` in the URL when the client sees: `www.domain.com/product/my-awesome-product-laser-pen`, htaccess alone isn't going to be able to help you.

Rewrite rules do simply that, they **rewrite** the requested URL. So unless there's a 191 in there somewhere, you're never going to be able to get `wwww.domain.com/product.php?id=191` out of that.

The best you can do is probably something like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ /product.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, in your `product.php` script, you're going to need to look for the `name` parameter, do a DB fetch or whatever this stuff is all stored in, and get an ID out of the DB based on the product's name.